# Combinatorics Example Question - Number of Solutions

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:  How many different 7-digit license plates are possible when 3 of the entries are letters and 4 are digits?  Assume that repetition of the letters and numbers is allowed and that there is no restriction on where the letters or numbers can be placed.**

This is how I approached the problem:

Assume I place the three letters.  Then there are 4 different places I could place the numbers:  _L_L_L_, represented by the underscores.  The underscore can be 0,1,2, or 3 letters.  This kind of problem is the "number of integer solutions of equations."

Hence, there are $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ distinct nonnegative integer valued vectors $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_r)$ satisfying the equation:  $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r = x_n \ for \  x_i \geq0$.

In this case, n=4 because you are placing 4 numbers and m=4 because there are 4 slots to place the letters.  So the solution is $\binom{7}{3}*26^3*10^4$.  This is in agreement with another post and matches my solution in the book:
[License plate consisting of 4 letters and 4 numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344498/license-plate-consisting-of-4-letters-and-4-numbers)

**Now here is my question.  Shouldn't I be able to place the numbers first and then apply the formula to the letters?  I tried and am not getting the same thing. So doing the same thing:
_N_N_N_N_.  Here, n=3 because there are 3 letters and m=5 because there are 5 places to place.  But this coefficient would give you $\binom{7}{4}$.  What am I misunderstanding?  Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${7 \choose 4}={7 \choose 3}$ and your logic is good

Comment: Thanks for confirming my logic.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that ${7 \choose 3}={7\choose 4}$. More generally there is a [symmetry identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Factorial_formula) that ${n \choose k}={n\choose n-k}$, for any integer $n,k$ satisfying $0\le k\le n$.

Comment: Yeah I forgot about that.  That can be seen from Pascal's Triangle because there is vertical symmetry.